# Что не так с regex в Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5.7

Нужно внедрить регулярное выражение в реквест файл Laravel. В сети скачал для php.

Код в методе rules():

```
  $data = [
       'name' => array('required','string', 'max:255', 'regex:/^([А-ЯЁ]{1}[а-яё]{255})|([A-Z]{1}[a-z]{255})$/u'),
       'lastname' => 'required|string|max:255',
       'sex' => 'boolean|nullable',
       'bio' => 'string|nullable|max:255',

  ];
```

На name = Александр возвращает, что не проходит. Параметры регулярки - нужно исключить спецсимволы, добавить букву ё и, чтобы начиналось с большой буквы.

Comment: Может быть дело в кодировке?

Comment: Как и что проверить? Я новичок в данных вопросах

Comment: В браузере в реквесте Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

Это скорее вопрос про регулярные выражения, а не laravel.

Вы пытаетесь проверять строку по типу первая буква заглавная, а потом за ней 255 прописных, а не от нуля или одной (или сколько нужно минимально) до 255).

Так будет правильно:

```
/^([А-ЯЁ]{1}[а-яё]{1,255})|([A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1,255})$/u
```